# How to iterate through the bytes of a void* in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, byte, void-pointers

What would be the best way to iterate through each byte of a void* buffer, and a assign a value to each depending on certain conditions?

```
        unsigned int bufSize = 100; //could be any value
        void* buffer = malloc(bufSize);
        char* bufferPointer = static_cast<char*>(buffer);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++){ 

            if (i % 2 == 0){
                bufferPointer[i] = 0x00;
            }
            else{
                bufferPointer[i] = 0xff;
            }
        }
        buffer = static_cast<void*>(bufferPointer);
```

Why doesn't this work? I tried converting to a char* to iterate over each byte.

Comment: You're using C++. You have better options than `malloc`. Additionally, if you're creating a character buffer, create a character buffer, not a C-style `void*` thing.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in this context?  What were you expecting, and what did you see that didn't meet that expectation?

Comment: What are the "better options"? In this case, the function inputs and outputs a void*, so I cannot change that.

Comment: `new char[bufSize]` at the very least. You can keep your `void*` but it is always going to be pointing to a buffer of "things", and `void` is not a "thing". Anyway the code looks basically functional so yes you're going to have to tell us what "it doesn't work" means for you.

Comment: '=': truncation of constant value is the warning.

Comment: Okay so it _does_ work, but you get a warning. 0xff doesn't fit in a char if char is signed so try unsigned char? That has nothing to do with iteration, though.

Comment: Additionally, the last statement `buffer = static_cast<void*>(bufferPointer);` is unneeded. `buffer` still points to the same memory that `bufferPointer` is pointing at.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the `void*` to an `unsigned char*`. You can then use *pointer arithmetic* to traverse the block of memory that you own, and set values by pointer dereference.

Remember that pointer arithmetic is only valid within arrays. For this purpose an object can be considered to be an array of length 1. Also, and perhaps confusingly, an array of N `int` elements will equate to an array of `N * sizeof(int)` `unsigned char` elements.